# Google Foobar Question - Please Pass The Coded Message (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

### Google Foobar Question:

Please Pass the Coded Messages
You need to pass a message to the bunny prisoners, but to avoid detection, the code you agreed to use is... obscure, to say the least. The bunnies are given food on standard-issue prison plates that are stamped with the numbers 0-9 for easier sorting, and you need to combine sets of plates to create the numbers in the code. The signal that a number is part of the code is that it is divisible by 3. You can do smaller numbers like 15 and 45 easily, but bigger numbers like 144 and 414 are a little trickier. Write a program to help yourself quickly create large numbers for use in the code, given a limited number of plates to work with.

You have L, a list containing some digits (0 to 9). Write a function answer(L) which finds the largest number that can be made from some or all of these digits and is divisible by 3. If it is not possible to make such a number, return 0 as the answer. L will contain anywhere from 1 to 9 digits. The same digit may appear multiple times in the list, but each element in the list may only be used once.

### Languages

To provide a Python solution, edit solution.py To provide a Java solution, edit solution.java

### **Test cases**

**-- Java cases --**
Input:
Solution.solution({3, 1, 4, 1})
Output:
    4311

Input:
Solution.solution({3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9})
Output:
    94311

Use verify [file] to test your solution and see how it does. When you are finished editing your code, use submit [file] to submit your answer. If your solution passes the test cases, it will be removed from your home folder.

---

That's the question. I have written a Java code for that which returns some error that I am unable to understand. Here's my code:

```
public class Main

{
     public static void main(String []args){
         Solution.solution({1,2,3,4}); //13th line
     }

} //16th line
class Solution {
int solution(int [] l) {
        int len=l.length;
            int sum=0;
            int c,a=0;

            for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                for(int j=(i+1);j<len;j++)
                {
                    if(l[i]<l[j])
                    {
                      c=l[i];
                      l[i]=l[j];
                      l[j]=c;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                sum+=l[i];
            }
            if (sum%3==0)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
                 {
                 System.out.print(""+l[i]);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--){

                    if((sum-l[i])%3==0){
                        a=l[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
                 {
                     if(a==l[i])
                     continue;
                 System.out.print(""+l[i]);
                }
            }


        // Your code here
         }
    }
```

PS:I have added the main class just to test the code on IDE.

---

Now the error:

```
Main.java:13: error: illegal start of expression
     Solution.solution({1,2,3,4});
                       ^
Main.java:13: error: ';' expected
         Solution.solution({1,2,3,4});
                            ^
Main.java:13: error: illegal start of expression
         Solution.solution({1,2,3,4});
                             ^
Main.java:13: error: ';' expected
         Solution.solution({1,2,3,4});
                              ^
Main.java:13: error: illegal start of expression
         Solution.solution({1,2,3,4});
                               ^
Main.java:13: error: ';' expected
         Solution.solution({1,2,3,4});
                                ^
Main.java:13: error: illegal start of expression
         Solution.solution({1,2,3,4});
                                 ^
Main.java:13: error: ';' expected
         Solution.solution({1,2,3,4});
                                  ^
Main.java:13: error: illegal start of type
         Solution.solution({1,2,3,4});
                                    ^
Main.java:16: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
10 errors
```

Comment: If you need to pass an array into method as a parameter, you need to use this syntax:
`Solution.solution(new int[]{1,2,3,4});`

Comment: Ya but then how to accept input in the form given in question? Because as long as I can't accept input in that format, My whole code is useless... 

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass {1,2,3,4} in method you need to pass a reference. Also since you are not creating instance of type Solution you need to make solution method static. Below is the working code. Also added a return since you are expecting an integer.

```
public class Main

{
     public static void main(String []args){

         int arr[] = {3, 1, 4, 1};
         Solution.solution(arr); //13th line
     }

} //16th line
class Solution {
static int  solution(int [] l) {
        int len=l.length;
            int sum=0;
            int c,a=0;

            for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                for(int j=(i+1);j<len;j++)
                {
                    if(l[i]<l[j])
                    {
                      c=l[i];
                      l[i]=l[j];
                      l[j]=c;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                sum+=l[i];
            }
            if (sum%3==0)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
                 {
                 System.out.print(""+l[i]);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--){

                    if((sum-l[i])%3==0){
                        a=l[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
                 {
                     if(a==l[i])
                     continue;
                 System.out.print(""+l[i]);
                }
            }

return 0;
        // Your code here
         }
    }
```

PS:- I just fixed your code for execution. Not validated the solution.

Comment: Ya but then how to accept input in the form given in question? Because as long as I can't accept input in that format, My whole code is useless... 